# Are questions about Hindu mythology allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Ok, this might be a silly question, but are we considering questions related to Hindu mythology on topic? Like questions related to the *Mahabharata*, *Ramayana*, and other mythological Hindu texts...

Comment: I don't see why we should not..

Comment: Myths and legends are integral part of Hinduism and I would go on to say that myths shape the religion from which it was built.

Comment: Anything related to `Hindu` is on-topic. Its a myth, information, question whatever. It would be on topic.

Comment: @Sisir I am not saying we should not, I am just asking, do we?

Comment: @VineetMenon Nice point, +1 :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Please add that as an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @AwalGarg done :)

Comment: Definitely we do, because some sampradayas consider the Mahabharata (Bhagavad-Gita) and Ramayana as scripture.

Comment: Yes, I think Hindu mythology is a vitally important part of what this site should be about.  I've already asked three mythology-based questions.  Tell me what you think of them.

Comment: For such types of questions, will act like fragments, and hence I've [asked a question](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29/what-types-of-questions-should-we-ask-here) where we can make a common post which will clear out on topic questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything related to Hindu is on-topic. Its a myth, information, question whatever. It would be on topic.

In the about section of this site. It has been stated clearly, that a person should ask question that are directly related to Hindu religion. So, if it is related to Mythology or what ever. It would be and should be on-topic if it is not opinion based and is understandable by the asker.

Comment: Well, not _anything_. We don't want [boat Hinduism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/224428) questions here.